# Android Application is not working in debug mode

Tags: android, debugging, gradle

I am facing a very strange behavior of my android app on lollipop(5.0.1).
When I built and deploy my app in debug mode  it crashes and if I put debuggable on "false" in the gradle file it runs without any crashes.

```
debug{
        debuggable false
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it working in release mode?

Comment: Can you share your logcat when crashed?

Comment: @NoumanCh yes its working in release mode

Comment: If it is working in release mode, maybe is about minify. So, can you change `minifyEnabled false` and try again ?

Comment: @Aytek I am not enabling minifyEnabled in debug mode.  This is not about minifyEnabled, I have test my app by running it with debuggable true and it get crashed, when I change it to false it works fine.